# 'backgroundColor' not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a tab menu like this:

```js
function clear_selected() //sets all columns color black
{
  var parent = document.querySelector("#container")
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item")
  var n = items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    items[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function plus(itself) //adds another column
{
  var parent = itself.parentElement;
  var n = parent.childElementCount;
  clear_selected();

  var n = parent.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
  var page = document.createElement("button");
  page.className = "item";
  page.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  page.textContent = "column"
  page.onclick = function() {
    clear_selected();
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  };

  var temp = document.createElement("span");
  temp.className = "del"
  temp.innerHTML = "&times;"
  temp.onclick = function() { //it's suppose to remove a column and color default as blue
    document.querySelector("#main_item").style.backgroundColor = "blue" //THIS LINE ISN'T WORKING
    this.parentElement.remove();
  };

  page.appendChild(temp);
  parent.insertBefore(page, parent.childNodes[n]);
}

function see(el) {
  clear_selected();
  el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  max-width: 100%;

}

.del {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0.7rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="item" id="main_item" style="background-color:blue;" onclick="see(this)">default column </button>
  <button class="item" onclick="plus(this)">+</button>
</div>
```

but when I press the 'x' to remove a column, I want the default column to color blue, but the line of code which is suppose to achieve that isn't working

> document.querySelector("#main_item").style.backgroundColor = "blue"

Before pressing 'x':
[image]

After pressing 'x' on the last column:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKOpJ.png]

What it SHOULD look like:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyEcm.png]

I've losing sleep over this, can someone PLEASE tell me why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the "X", both of your `onclick` handlers are getting called, including the one that runs `clear_selected`, which sets the background color to `""`.

You can fix this by using `stopPropagation` on the event passed into the `onclick` function for the "x". That will stop the click event from going up the chain to the parent element of the "x".

```
temp.onclick = function(e) {
    document.querySelector("#main_item").style.backgroundColor = "blue" 
    this.parentElement.remove();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
```

Comment: thank you so much! I can finally sleep in peace!
although it works, I'm still having a bit of problem understanding what you did 
(i'm new to js)
could you provide some links for prerequisites I need to know so I can understand this better? :)

Comment: The gist of it is the onclick event is getting passed up the view hierarchy (sometimes called "bubbling"), so the `onclick` for both the "X" and the parent view are getting called. `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation